# I need assistance with recursive TSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in getting the path traversed.
Consider the Table below:

| ID | NextID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | null |
| 8 | null |
| 9 | 10 |
| 10 | null |

Id is unique. NextID stores the next ID value. When NextID value is Null, there the path Ends.

In this table, the possible path will be:

```
a. 1 --> 5 --> 8 
b. 2
c. 3 -->6 -->9 -->10
d. 4-->7
e. 8
```

I have written one query but not working as needed.

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    ID VARCHAR(10),
    NextID VARCHAR(10)
)
    
INSERT Data VALUES ('1','5'), ('2','Null'),
    ('3','6'), ('4','7'), ('5','8'), ('6','9'),
    ('7','Null'), ('8','Null'), ('9','10'),
    ('10','Null');
      
;WITH RecursivePaths AS (
    SELECT ID, NextID, CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path
    FROM Data
    WHERE ID = 3  -- Starting point, adjust as needed

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT t.ID, t.NextID, r.Path + ' --> ' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM Data t
    JOIN RecursivePaths r ON t.ID = r.NextID
    WHERE t.NextID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Path
FROM RecursivePaths
```

Here I have to give starting ID which is not desired.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduceable example including DDL/DML (something like:
`DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col INT, Col2 DATE, ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Col, Col2, ...) VALUES (1, '2023-11-14', ...), (1, '2023-11-15', ....);` Please demonstrate your expected output in a parseable format, such as a table (you can use markdown in your question like: `|Col|Col2|
|:---|:---|
|1|2023-11-14|
|2|2023-11-14|` )

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Replacing unformatted text with images is not helpful, useful, or an improvement.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to read [ask], and the instructions in the [t-sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/t-sql/info) on how to ask good t-sql questions.

Comment: What have you tried? I would guess you need to look into recursive ctes.

Comment: Is `Source` distinct across the entire data set? Distinct within the same category? Or can it appear multiple times with potentially different destinations on different dates? The solutions to these cases would be different.

Comment: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744/3404097)

Comment: You have completely rewritten your question, which makes if very difficult for someone for follow up with a useful response. That said, you do not currently state a clear question. You seem to have a working recursive CTE, but it is unclear if the results are as you intended. You do not state what your expected/desired results are.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP replaced the original question with a different one.

Answer (score 1):

This actually looks like gaps and islands in disguise. A possible solution:

```sql
select  datenew 
,   source, destination, Category
,   FIRST_VALUE(Destination) OVER(PARTITION BY category, grp ORDER BY dateNew DESC) AS final_destination -- Take first value ordered by last date per group
from (
    select  *
    ,   sum(flag)over(partition by category order by dateNew) as grp -- 2. Create grouping
    from (
        select  case when lag(destination) over(partition by category order by cast(date as date)) = source then 0 else 1 end as flag -- 1. Watch me for the changes
        ,   cast(date as date) as dateNew
        ,   *
        from
        (
            VALUES  (N'04-14-2020', N'AA', N'AC', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'06-02-2020', N'AC', N'AD', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'07-22-2020', N'AD', N'BB', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'10-22-2020', N'BB', N'DM', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'06-07-2021', N'BM', N'CD', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'08-09-2021', N'CD', N'QR', N'T', NULL)
            ,   (N'08-07-2021', N'BW', N'BW', N'M', NULL)
            ,   (N'05-11-2020', N'OR', N'BO', N'M', NULL)
        ) t (Date,Source,Destination,Category,final_destination)
        ) x
    ) x
order by category DESC, datenew
```

The first two steps are standard:

1. Create a flag field that increments every time there's a change from previous destination. I'm guessing you wanted to group by Category, if that's wrong assumption, you can remove the partition by part
2. Summarize the flag by creating a rolling SUM, this creates a group of destinations that belongs together
3. Since you need the last destination per group, we use FIRST_VALUE window function that gets the desired value.

Output:

| datenew | source | destination | Category | final_destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-14 | AA | AC | T | DM |
| 2020-06-02 | AC | AD | T | DM |
| 2020-07-22 | AD | BB | T | DM |
| 2020-10-22 | BB | DM | T | DM |
| 2021-06-07 | BM | CD | T | QR |
| 2021-08-09 | CD | QR | T | QR |
| 2020-05-11 | OR | BO | M | BO |
| 2021-08-07 | BW | BW | M | BW |

Comment: I think this may not work for the general case, since it assumes no overlapping progressions. If I add the data `,  (N'07-01-2020', N'XX', N'YY', N'T', NULL),   (N'07-02-2020', N'YY', N'ZZ', N'T', NULL)` to the mix, the `XX > YY > ZZ` progression breaks up the `AA > AC > AD > BB > DM` progression. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aTR2sSk-). (That mostly an issue of oversimplified test data and/or underspecified requirements from the OP.) I suspect a recursive CTE is needed, as Sean suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume a much more general case than is indicated by the test data.

1. The chains of progression can be intermixed.
2. Multiple rows (with different sources) can have the same immediate destination.
3. When chaining destinations, the earliest matching row after the current row is to be selected.
4. A source might appear more than once with different dates in different progressions.

To trace all of the paths through the data, it is best to start with the final destination rows (those with no successor) and recursively work our way back to find all of the matching predecessors. A recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) is one way to do this.

However, before we can trace the links, we need to identify the logical successor for each row. This can also be done with a CTE. For convenience, another CTE can be used to temporarily assign distinct row IDs, so that those links can be easily represented as a single NextId value.

The result would be a progression of CTEs followed by a final select.

```
;WITH CTE_Numbered AS (
    -- Assign arbitrary unique IDs
    SELECT D.*, Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Data D
),
CTE_Linked AS (
    -- Identify the successor ID for each row (null if final)
    SELECT N.*, NextId = N2.Id
    FROM CTE_Numbered N
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 N2.Id
        FROM CTE_Numbered N2
        WHERE N2.Category = N.Category
        AND N2.Date > N.Date
        AND N2.Source = N.Destination
        ORDER BY N2.Date
    ) N2
),
CTE_Chained AS (
    -- Recursively join the final destinations back to all predicessors
    SELECT L.*, L.Destination AS Final_Destination
    FROM CTE_Linked L
    WHERE L.NextId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT L.*, C.Final_Destination AS Final_Destination
    FROM CTE_Chained C
    JOIN CTE_Linked L
        ON L.NextId = C.Id
)
SELECT C.*
FROM CTE_Chained C
ORDER BY C.Category DESC, C.Date
```

Results (with some extra test data):

| Date | Source | Destination | Category | Id | NextId | Final_Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-14 | AA | AC | T | 1 | 2 | DM |
| 2020-06-02 | AC | AD | T | 2 | 5 | DM |
| 2020-07-01 | XX | YY | T | 3 | 4 | ZZ |
| 2020-07-02 | YY | ZZ | T | 4 | null | ZZ |
| 2020-07-22 | AD | BB | T | 5 | 6 | DM |
| 2020-10-22 | BB | DM | T | 6 | null | DM |
| 2021-06-07 | BM | CD | T | 7 | 8 | QR |
| 2021-08-09 | CD | QR | T | 8 | null | QR |
| 2020-05-11 | OR | BO | M | 10 | null | BO |
| 2021-08-07 | BW | BW | M | 9 | null | BW |
| 2022-01-01 | GA | GD | G | 11 | 14 | GE |
| 2022-01-02 | GB | GC | G | 12 | 13 | GE |
| 2022-01-03 | GC | GE | G | 13 | null | GE |
| 2022-01-04 | GD | GE | G | 14 | null | GE |
| 2022-01-05 | GA | GB | G | 15 | 16 | GC |
| 2022-01-06 | GB | GC | G | 16 | null | GC |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H3zWoYMX) that also contains some extra test data.

Comment: This Query helped partially, But the recursive one is taking too long time while running in DB with 6K Records (not finished in 20 min)

Comment: The recursion probably needs an index. This can be done by populating a `#CTE_Numbered` temp table with the results of the `CTE_Numbered` query, adding an index on `#CTE_Numbered(Category, Source, Date)` and then feeding that into the rest of the query. If there are still performance issues, you can store the result of the `CTE_Linked` query into a second `#CTE_Linked` temp table and add an index on `#CTE_Linked(NextId)`.

Comment: See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d-yy4Pvu).

Comment: If your original data already has unique ID values (such as a primary key), you can skip the first step and use your existing IDs. You would still need an index on `(Category, Source, Date)` - a compound index in that order. Also, if your source data has many more columns than shown in your example, the first query should be modified to just select the needed data instead of `*`.